# Code not working when adding 1 day to date

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code, which generates timeslots between `$start` and `$end`, with lengths of the `$interval` variable.

```
$schedule = [];
$start = strtotime('04/09/2019 09:00');
$end = strtotime('04/09/2019 19:00');
$interval = '30';

while ($start < $end) {

    $next = strtotime("+{$interval} minutes", $start);
    $schedule[] = [
            'startTime' => date('H:i', $start),
            'endTime' => date('H:i', $next)
        ];
    $start = $next;
};

print_r($schedule);
```

It returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [startTime] => 09:00
            [endTime] => 09:30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [startTime] => 09:30
            [endTime] => 10:00
        )

    ...

    [18] => Array
        (
            [startTime] => 18:00
            [endTime] => 18:30
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [startTime] => 18:30
            [endTime] => 19:00
        )

)
```

However when I add 1 day to the `$start` and `$end` variables, like:

`$start = strtotime('04/10/2019 09:00');
$end = strtotime('04/10/2019 19:00');`

It returns an empty array, why does this happen?

Comment: Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: I'm thinking here. But... coming up empty. Can you print out `$start` and `$end` before looping to inspect the values. Perhaps print out your variables while looping as well. Something is off here, but I don't think it's your code. I'm suspecting I'm not alone in that thought since no one else has popped up here yet.

Comment: I appriciate your help. When printing $start I get 1554793200 and 1554829200 for $end. It's because they're time objects I guess..

Comment: Is the code working with both dates on your end?

Comment: Those time values look fine to me. Just tested at phptester.net because I'm baffled. I was able to make it work just fine with both dates, so it's not this bit of code you've shared.

Comment: It doesn't return an empty array. https://3v4l.org/LhIKt